# Connecting SQL database to Airflow in Google Cloud Composer

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

hope all are well. I have a DAG running in the Google Cloud Composer. But, I am having an issue connecting sql db for the DAG.

- One way I tried was to export my local SQLite db file to Google Cloud Bucket. Then add the URL of this to the Airflow Web UI connections by selecting type as SQLite and host as link to the db file in bucket. But the DAG is getting failed stating that it can’t find the database. Where test button in the connections tab in Airflow Web UI is saying that it cannot open the database.
- Another way I tried was by launching a Google Cloud SQL instance and importing the db to that. However I am not sure what option to select in the Airflow Web UI connections tab for this.

First way:

- DAG:

```
from airflow.providers.sqlite.operators.sqlite import SqliteOperator
from airflow.providers.sqlite.hooks.sqlite import SqliteHook
def podcast_summary():
    create_database = SqliteOperator(
        task_id='create_table_sqlite',
        sql=r"""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS episodes (
            link TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
            title TEXT,
            filename TEXT,
            published TEXT,
            description TEXT,
            transcript TEXT
        );
        """,
        sqlite_conn_id="episodes"
    )

    @task()
    def get_episodes():
        data = requests.get(PODCAST_URL)
        feed = xmltodict.parse(data.text)
        episodes = feed["rss"]["channel"]["item"]
        print(f"Found {len(episodes)} episodes.")
        return episodes

    podcast_episodes = get_episodes()
    create_database.set_downstream(podcast_episodes)
summary = podcast_summary()
```

- Airflow WebUI Connection:
  [image: Where conn_id is episodes, type is sqlite and host is the file location in the Google Cloud Bucket]